# unbind('click') not working

Tags: jquery

When i press  `$('.walk-previous-button')`  i want to disable the click event until the animation is finished.  The below isn't working.

```
$('.walk-previous-button').live('click',function() {
        var stringcontainer = $('#walk-string-parent-container');

    $('.walk-previous-button').unbind('click'); 

        stringcontainer.animate({'scrollLeft': '-=340'}, 1500,function() {
    $('.walk-previous-button').bind('click');
    //code
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to check if the element is being animated.

```
$('.walk-previous-button').live('click',function() {
    if(!$(this).is(':animated')){
      var stringcontainer = $('#walk-string-parent-container');
      stringcontainer.animate({'scrollLeft': '-=340'}, 1500, function(){
        // code
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.walk-previous-button:not(:animated)').live('click',function(){
    var stringcontainer = $('#walk-string-parent-container');
    stringcontainer.animate({'scrollLeft': '-=340'}, 1500, function(){
        // code
    });
});
```

Only bind it to elements that are not animated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `live` unbind on `$('.walk-previous-button')` will not work, use `die` instead to remove any event handlers attached using `live`.

```
$('.walk-previous-button').die('click');
```

If there is no specific reason to use `live` then use `click` then you can use `bind('click')` and `unbind('click')` to bind/unbind the event handler.

As @Rocket has suggested you can also check if the element is being animated using `:animated` selector and then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery 1.7+

```
$(document).on('click', '.walk-previous-button' ,AnimateWalkString);

function AnimateWalkString() {
    $(document).off('click', '.walk-previous-button' ,AnimateWalkString);
    var elm = $('#walk-string-parent-container');
    elm.animate({'scrollLeft': '-=340'}, 1500, function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.walk-previous-button' ,AnimateWalkString);
    });
}
```

Or just set a flag

```
var flag=true;
$('.walk-previous-button').live('click', function() {
    if (flag) {
        flag=false;
        var elm = $('#walk-string-parent-container');
        elm.animate({'scrollLeft': '-=340'}, 1500,function() {
            flag=true;
        });
    }
});
```